# Access UNC share from IIS python CGI script

Tags: python, iis, cgi, nas

I need to access a file on a UNC share from Python (3.6) CGI script, running on IIS (7.5). My minimal test example is:

```
import os
import psutil
print('Content-Type: text/html\n')
print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).username())
print(os.path.exists('\\\\<server name>\\<folder>'))
```

When I run this script from the command line, it prints the desired output:

```
> python cgi-bin\test.py
Content-Type: text/html

<domain>\<my username>
True
```

When I run it over IIS by accessing `http://localhost/my-site/cgi-bin/test.py`, however, I get:

```
<domain>\<my username>
False
```

Note that I set the following in the IIS configuration:

- AppPool identity is set to my `<domain>\<my username>`.
- The website is set to "Connect as..." my `<domain>\<my username>`.

What really confuses me is that running the script over the IIS prints the correct process owner (me), same as when running the script from the command line. However, in one case I can access the UNC share, in the other case it fails.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a network drive? i.e.: mapping some drive on the UNC share. Anyway the problem may be that IIS is run on Windows with a specific user (IIS_IUSRS) that may not have rights to access your shared folder.

Comment: I have tried mapping the network drive but got the same result.